# Issue while trying to implement Paypal Create Order API

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox

**About the issue**

This is about create order api in Paypal. **[Documentation link is here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create)** I am trying to pass below payload, so that the request could have my return and cancel url and everything works perfectly.

```
"intent": "CAPTURE",
"purchase_units": [
    {
        "amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "100.00"
        }
    }
],
"application_context" => [
    "return_url" => "my return url",
    "cancel_url" => "my cancel url"
]
```

**[Just the return and cancel url has gone deprerated in application_context.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-application_context)**

To overcome this problem, I removed `application_context` from payload and added `payment_source` like below which has return and cancel url

```
"intent": "CAPTURE",
"purchase_units": [
    {
        "amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "100.00"
        }
    }
],
"payment_source": {
    "paypal": {
        "experience_context": {
            "return_url": "return Url",
            "cancel_url": "cancel Url"
        }
    }
}
```

> Now, it gives an error message - PAYPAL_REQUEST_ID_REQUIRED

**I need to pass return and cancel url and at this stage I only need to create the request to let user go to checkout page. that's it. I really don't have any payment info yet.**

Comment: read the documentation https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/orders/v2/errors/

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error message "PAYPAL_REQUEST_ID_REQUIRED", you need to including a unique identifier in the "request_id" field in the payload.

something like:

```
[
   "intent":"CAPTURE",
   "purchase_units":[
      {
         "amount":{
            "currency_code":"USD",
            "value":"100.00"
         }
      }
   ],
   "payment_source":{
      "paypal":{
         "experience_context":{
            "return_url":"return Url",
            "cancel_url":"cancel Url"
         }
      }
   },
   "request_id":"UNIQUE_REQUEST_ID"
]
```

You may also verify that the return and cancel URLs provided in the payload are valid and accessible.

Comment: why should I even include payment_source when there is no payment information in the object? Is there any other way to correctly add cancel and return url in payload?

Comment: here "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/" you can see an example in the right side for the payment_source

Comment: ok, I have added the request id and payment_source object is already there is request as mentioned in my question then why does it issue an error with status code 422- Client error: `POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders` resulted in a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response: {"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":[{"field":"/payment_source","issue":"NO_PAYMENT_SOURCE_PROVIDED","description": (truncated...)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `payment_source` add `"request_id": "YOUR_UNIQUE_REQUEST_ID"`

Your system can *generate* this `request Id` yourself and *must be unique* to prevent getting error message `DUPLICATED_REQUEST_ID`

See here in documentation https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/requests

**PayPal-Request-Id**
*"Optional. Contains a unique user-generated ID that the server stores for a period of time. Use this header to enforce idempotency on REST API POST calls. ...."*

Comment: ok, I have added the request id and payment_source object is already there is request as mentioned in my question then why does it issue an error with status code 422- Client error: `POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders` resulted in a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response: {"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":[{"field":"/payment_source","issue":"NO_PAYMENT_SOURCE_PROVIDED","description": (truncated...)

Comment: i think the issue is clear , no payment source provided , please provide a real payment method for paypal , check this link https://support.paykickstart.com/knowledge-base/paypal-error-payment-can-not-processed-no-payment-source-available/ .... not sure why since you use paypal sandbox

Answer (score 0):

You need request_id could you try including reference_id.

```
{
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "reference_id": "d9f80740-38f0-11e8-b467-0ed5f89f718b",
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "100.00"
      }
    }
  ],
  "payment_source": {
    "paypal": {
      "experience_context": {
        "return_url": "https://example.com/returnUrl",
        "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancelUrl"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is when:
The request is not well-formed, is syntactically incorrect, or violates schema:
https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/orders/v2/errors/

I could solve it changing it for this sintaxis:

```
/**
 * Recibe el valor de la orden de pago y la moneda
 */
public function createOrder($value, $currency)
{
    return $this->makeRequest(
        'POST',
        '/v2/checkout/orders',
        [],//queryParams
        [
            'intent' => 'CAPTURE',//required
            'purchase_units' => [//required
                0 => [
                    'amount' => [
                        'currency_code' => strtoupper($currency),
                        'value' => $value,
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            //'payment_source' => [
                //'paypal' => [
                    'experience_context' => [
                        'payment_method_preference' => 'IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED',
                        'payment_method_selected' => 'PAYPAL',
                        'brand_name' => config('app.name'),
                        //'locale' => 'es-ES', -> cambiar?
                        //'landing_page' => 'LOGIN', ?
                        'shipping_preference' => 'NO_SHIPPING',
                        'user_action' => 'PAY_NOW',
                        'return_url' => route('approval'),
                        'cancel_url' => route('cancelled'), 
                    ],
                //]
            //],
            
        ],//cuerpo
        [],//cabeceras
        $isJsonRequest = true,//es un json lo que viene
    );
}
```

But I am using Guzzle client in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Add and pass the header key as "PayPal-Request-Id" and for value you can pass any unique ID. It has to be unique for every transaction.
Adding this header should fix issue for you.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/orders/v2/errors/

```
PAYPAL_REQUEST_ID_REQUIRED: A PayPal-Request-Id is required if you are trying to process payment for an Order. Please specify a PayPal-Request-Id or Create the Order without a payment_source specified.
```

Add this param in your headers

```
PayPal-Request-Id   
string [ 1 .. 36 ] characters
The server stores keys for 6 hours. The API callers can request the times to up to 72 hours by speaking to their Account Manager.
```